# Using rowspan in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

Is it possible to have `rowspan="2.5"`? I using this in creating a timetable using HTML tables. I have 1-hour interval and I need to show a time with 30-mins. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you show us your code snippet?

Comment: You should have a row for each 30 minute interval.

Comment: That's what I thought at first. But the number of time intervals would double. That's too messy. But thanks :)

Comment: Some years ago, I was working at a well known new media company with some very smart people who came to the conclusion that for timetables, a set of lists was a better markup choice than tables.

Comment: @Quentin When you've multiple days (and so many columns), a table is still a valid solution imo and it has a design advantage because all cells in a row will be of same height due to the table layout with no constraint of fixed height. On the other hand, IE9 won't let you change this table layout (for example with `display: block` on narrow screens). But then IE9 has no marketshare on mobile so it isn't too annoying...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have decimals for rowspan/colspan values.  Not only [does the spec say so](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/td) (they must be integers), but that wouldn't make sense.

What you can do instead is simply make each row 30 minutes instead of an hour.  Then, just double that rowspan (5 instead of 2.5).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could go for an illusion. Nest another table with two rows inside your td. Have the upper row use the background-color of the td above it, and apply this rule to the lower row.

That way you won't have to completely rewrite your tables. It's a lazy way, true, but I see no reason why it would not work.